# Proxy Laravel, как?

Tags: php, laravel, proxy

От пользователя приходит запрос с адресом (uri) и дополнительными данными.
В моих задачах стоит отправить *get* запрос на данный адрес с использованием *proxy*. Никогда не работал с *proxy*. Перед каждым запросом нужно менять *ip* откуда будет идти запрос на *uri* адрес (данный пользователем).

Вопрос: Как?

Использую *laravel 5.2*

Answer (score 1):

Если используете Guzzle для выполнения серверных запросов, то необходимо определить глобальную переменную HTTP_PROXY со значением http://ip:port. Для HTTPS аналогично.
Подробнее [тут](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=proxy#environment-variables).